# PHP Class Variable

Tags: php, laravel, global-variables, laravel-5.3

I know there are some threads about it already but nothing seems to work... I'm trying to make something like a global class variable in PHP, so in theory I want something like that:

(PseudoCode follows):

```
class GlobalVarClass{

globalVar $price;

function doSomethingWithThePrice(){

    //get some Values, etc..
    $this->price = $xyz;

}

function needThePriceNow(){
    //this is where the price is needed now, so something like
    echo $this->price;
}

}
```

How can I do this? Btw.: I can NOT set this value in constructor, as there I have it not available yet....

I'm using Laravel btw., if this makes something easier...

Edit: 
To be exact, this is the code I have:

```
class VoucherController extends Controller
{
    private $_apiContext;

    protected $voucherValue;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->_apiContext = PayPal::ApiContext(
            config('services.paypal.client_id'),
            config('services.paypal.secret'));

        $this->_apiContext->setConfig(array(
            'mode' => 'sandbox',
            'service.EndPoint' => 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com',
            'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 30,
            'log.LogEnabled' => true,
            'log.FileName' => storage_path('logs/paypal.log'),
            'log.LogLevel' => 'FINE'
        ));

    }

    public function index(){
        return view('voucher.createVoucher');
    }

    public function payVoucher(Request $request){
        $userInfo = \App\User::where('id','=',\Auth::user()->id)
            ->first();

        if($userInfo->street == ""){
            $request->session()->flash('alert-info', 'Vor der ersten Bestellung müssen Sie erst Ihre Daten vervollständigen');
            return redirect('/editData');
        }

        $itemList = PayPal::itemList();

        $payPalItem = PayPal::item();
        $payPalItem->setName('Gutschein')->setDescription('Gutschein für Shopping Portal')->setCurrency('EUR')->setQuantity(1)->setPrice($request->input('voucherValue'));

        $total = $request->input('voucherValue');

        $this->voucherValue = $total;

        $itemList->addItem($payPalItem);

        $payer = PayPal::Payer();
        $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

        $details = PayPal::details();
        $details->setShipping("0")
            ->setSubtotal($total);

        $amount = PayPal:: Amount();
        $amount->setCurrency('EUR');
        $amount->setTotal(($total));
        $amount->setDetails($details);

        $transaction = PayPal::Transaction();
        $transaction->setAmount($amount);
        $transaction->setItemList($itemList);
        $transaction->setDescription('Ihr Gutschein');

        $redirectUrls = PayPal:: RedirectUrls();
        $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(action('VoucherController@getDone'));
        $redirectUrls->setCancelUrl(action('VoucherController@getCancel'));

        $payment = PayPal::Payment();
        $payment->setIntent('sale');
        $payment->setPayer($payer);
        $payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);
        $payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));

        $response = $payment->create($this->_apiContext);

        $redirectUrl = $response->links[1]->href;

        return Redirect::to($redirectUrl);
    }


    public function getDone(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->get('paymentId');
        $token = $request->get('token');
        $payer_id = $request->get('PayerID');

        $payment = PayPal::getById($id, $this->_apiContext);

        $paymentExecution = PayPal::PaymentExecution();

        $paymentExecution->setPayerId($payer_id);
        $executePayment = $payment->execute($paymentExecution, $this->_apiContext);

        // Clear the shopping cart, write to database, send notifications, etc.

        // Thank the user for the purchase

        //Gutscheincode generieren, in DB eintragen, und per Mail verschicken

        $voucherCode = substr(base_convert(sha1(uniqid(mt_rand())), 16, 36), 0, 12);
        $voucher = new Voucher;
        $voucher->voucherValue = $this->voucherValue;
        $voucher->voucherCode = $voucherCode;
        $voucher->save();

        return view('voucher.buyDone', ['voucherCode' => $voucherCode, 'payment' => $payment]);
    }
```

So I'm doing a PayPal payment. In the function `payVoucher`, I get the voucherValue (which is the variable that should be accessible in the other function) from the `request`, then in the function `getDone` I need to access it to enter it into the DB. How can I do this?

Comment: for the one that downvoted: thanks for not telling me why at least ;)

the problem is that the variable seems to stay undefined all time, It's a object var, so I tried using one of those but it is undefined when I try to use it in the 2nd function

Comment: @jeroen I edited my question to use my real code, just thought it might be hardly confusing, because `PayPal` is not what the question is about..

Comment: Is this in the same request, or is it after for example a redirect? Your code seems to suggest a redirect; in that case you'd need more persistent storage like a session or a database.

Comment: @jeroen yeah, the 2nd function (`getDone`) is called from a redirect, thats right... You mean it then doesn't work any more because it's another instance or something? If I wanted to save it in the session, could I just use `$_SESSION['voucherValue'] = $voucherValue;` and then access it with '$_SESSION['voucherValue']`? If yes, how can I delete it afterwards? Storing it in the db would not make sence in my case, as I want to do it after the payment is done, not before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, the second method is called after a redirect. That is a new request and as all variables you set in your script cease to exist when the script finishes, your original object with the properties you set will no longer exist.

There are several ways to pass the value to the new request, like a query variable in the url, a session variable or for example database storage.

Using a session or some other kind of server-side storage keeps the value on the server so that is what I would recommend:

```
public function payVoucher(Request $request){
    ...
    $_SESSION['PayPal']['voucherValue'] = $total;
    ...
}


public function getDone(Request $request)
{
    ...
    $voucher->voucherValue = $_SESSION['PayPal']['voucherValue'];
    // You need to delete it?
    unset($_SESSION['PayPal']['voucherValue']);
    ...
}
```

Note that I am assuming that a session has been started at the top of the script.

Comment: this works! thank you... the thing, that there's a new object created after the redirect was the thing I forgot about, that's why it didn't work then... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
protected $price;
```

Comment: same problem... I'll edit my answer with the real complete code

Comment: So why you want another class, you can do this in same controller...just for assign a value don't use class.

Comment: that's exactly what I'm trying to do, using it in the `payVoutcher` function as well as in the `getDone` function, but I somehow need to save the value I get from the request in the `payVoutcher` function to use in the `getDone` function

Answer (score 0):

```
class GlobalVarClass{

public $price;

public function __construct(){
   $this->price = 123;
}


function needThePriceNow(){
    //this is where the price is needed now, so something like
    echo $this->price; //This will give 123;
}

}
```

Comment: as I wrote in the question, the value is not accessible in the contstructor, so I can't assign in the constructor

Comment: You can omit the constructor. `public $price;` should work when you call it later to assign a value

Comment: using $this->price = 0 in the constructor removes the error but still, the new value isn't stored